# rails : stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Actually i'm on a project for a model many->many. I need to find with a current user all credits/devices/project (and I think it's useless to have a table credit with only two column (id & score) so I merge this table to the join table).

I get this error :

```
SystemStackError in Users#show

Showing app/views/shared/_credit.html.erb where line # raised:

stack level too deep
```

And the two model :

```
class **Credit** < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at, :credit_id, :device_id, :project_id, :score, :user_id

belongs_to :device
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :score

end

class **User** < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :credit
has_many :credit, :through => :credit, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

Thank !

Best.

Comment: Are you aware of the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship? Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association. Also, when you say `has_many`, it has to be `credits` instead of just `credit`.

Comment: You have defined 2 `has_many :credit`; I think the second one `should be `projects`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack level to deep points to an infinitive recursive call, and I would say you get that with

```
has_many :credit, :through => :credit,
```

which clearly introduces a cycle of some sort.